# Relation between column in one table

Tags: sql-server, database, constraints, nullable

I have following table:

```
Create table Rent
(
Id int not null,
Id_car int not null,
Date_rent date not null,
Date_return date,
Id_pleace_rent int not null,
Id_pleace_return int
)
```

I would like to add constraint that if in the same row in column "Date_return" is NULL then in column "Id_pleace_return" must be NULL too. How can I make this?

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Rent
ADD CONSTRAITN CK_Rent_Verify_Return
CHECK(
    Date_return IS NULL AND Id_pleace_return IS NULL 
    OR Date_return IS NOT NULL -- AND Id_pleace_return IS NOT NULL 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this is SQL server so it should be something along these lines:

```
ALTER TABLE Rent
ADD CONSTRAINT Nullability
CHECK (
(CASE WHEN Date_return IS NULL AND Id_pleace_return IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

)
GO
```